# How to find if one of the element is present after the page is displayed

Tags: protractor

The protractor has to verify whether the error message is present in the page. So the error message can be either in "alert-message" class or in "fail-heading" class.

If i do like below it is successful only if the alert-message className is displayed. But sometimes i get the className as "fail-heading".

```
var waitforele_confirmation = by.className('alert-message');
browser.wait(function(){return browser.driver.isElementPresent(waitforele_confirmation)}, 60000);
expect(browser.driver.isElementPresent(waitforele_confirmation)).toBeTruthy();
```

So i want to dynamically check which element is present after the page is loaded. Also i want to use the browser.wait function when waiting for each element. I just did the below pseudo code just to understand.

```
while (i<120 and !found)
{
    int i=0;
    if (element(by.className('alert-message')).isPresent())
    {
    found = true;
    }
    else if (element(by.className('fail-heading')).isPresent())
    {
    found = true;
    }
    else
    {
    browser.sleep(500);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Can someone convert the pseudo code in protractor pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
let alertMessageVisibility = EC.visibilityOf($('.alert-message'));
let failHeadingVisibility = EC.visibilityOf($('.fail-heading'));

browser.wait(EC.or(alertMessageVisibility, failHeadingVisibility), 60000, "Alert message or fail heading should become visible in 60 seconds, but it wasn't")
```

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work as you expected:

```
 var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 var alertMessageElement = element(by.className('alert-message'))
 var failHeadingElement = element(by.className('fail-heading'))

/*browser.wait() will be keep on checking for error messages until either   
any one of the error message found or specified timeout limit reached*/

browser.wait(function(){
EC.visibilityOf(alertMessageElement).call().then(function(isAlertMessagePres
 ent){
    if(isAlertMessagePresnt){
    return true;
  }
})

EC.visibilityOf(failHeadingElement).call().then(function(isFailedHeadingPresent)   {
 if(isFailedHeadingPresent){
    return true;
}
 })
   },10000,'No error message found within specified timeout of 10 seconds    
       ');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am getting syntax error with this code. I am new to protractor, so couldn't resolve the syntax issue. However the below answer (xotabu4) is working good.

    E/launcher - Error: C:\Protractor\POC\testcases_n_spec.js:97
                        return if (isPresent()){return true;}
                                   ^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: Removed return beside if statement. Try it now if you would like other option for your problem. Thanks

Comment: I tried again, its not working. Getting the below error.                                                                              Failed: isPresent is not defined. I tried giving isPresent(), still it is same error. Anyway the issue is resolved. We can close this issue.

Comment: okay, i got it. changed the isPresent  corresponding values.Thanks